# What are the rewards for playing multiplayer on each difficulty?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

Are there differences in the amount of credits, experience and galactic readiness earned between bronze, silver, and gold difficulties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is only a partial answer but I'm looking for how much experience and creds you get from gold too so I thought I'd pass the info along.

Bronze: About 150,000 experience, 15,000 credits.
Silver: About 200,000 Experience, 30,000 credits.
Gold: Unkown

As far as galactic readiness goes, I haven't really been watching but it's usually around plus 3% each time I think.

Comment: I played a fair bit of multiplayer last night and it seemed like the amount that galactic readiness increased went down with successive matches. Maybe it has diminishing returns as the percentage goes up?

Answer (score 5):

OmegaEffect answered Bronze and Silver.

Gold: ~250k Experience, ~75k credits.